# How to make marker appear on the surface of image overlay onclicked in react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I am using React leaflet together with custom CRS, [Leaflet CRS docs](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html)

**What I want to do is:**

1. A custom image is display at the map container as `ImageOverlay`
2. When user clicked on a position on the Image, a marker will display on top of the `ImageOverlay`

So the illustration is like this:
[image]

Here is my attempt:

The map container

```
<MapContainer
    center={[250, 500]}
    zoom={0}
    style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}
    crs={L.CRS.Simple as CRS}
    maxZoom={2}
    zoomControl={false}
    doubleClickZoom={false}
    scrollWheelZoom={false}
    dragging={false}
    >
    <MapClick />

     {/**This is where I display the marker */}
    {routePoints.map((point, index) => (
    <Marker
        key={index}
        position={point}
        icon={L.icon({
        iconUrl: `${playerMarkerAssest}`,
        iconSize: [35, 35],
        })}
    />
    ))}

    {/**This is the image url */}
    <ImageOverlay url={mapAssest} bounds={imageBounds} />
</MapContainer>
```

useMapEvents

```
useMapEvents({
    click: (e) => {
        setRoutePoints([...routePoints, e.latlng]);
    },
  });
```

In the code above, when user clicked on any position, the `LatLngExpression[]` will set into any array named `RoutePoints`

then display the marker according to the `routePoints` (The point user clicked on)`

Right now, the problem is,
When user click on a position only the `ImageOverlay`, the marker is display at somewhere else. Which will like illustration below:

[image]
*When user click on the position on top, the marker appeared at the bottom*

Please let me know what I missing out, and how to achieve what I want as described above.

Attach a screen recording to describe the question as well
https://youtu.be/o5Hh80WjJ80

**Update 2/7/2023:**

I have console log both value of `clicked point` and the `route points` (in array),

I clicked at 1 point, the value is

```
useMapEvents({
    click: (e) => {
         console.log(e.latlng)
```

The value is:

```
{
  lat: 530
  lng: -37
}
```

and checked the `routePoint` array as well

```
[{
  lat: 530
  lng: -37
}]
```

```
console.log('route points', routePoints);
```

both value is actually the same

[image: result in console]

But the actual result in UI is still appear the same, aka, "Clicked on top, but marker is appear at the bottom".

Please help

Comment: obviously the problem comes from the physical frames you need to tell us when you click on the top what `routePoints` is worth

Comment: @TachibanaShin hey, I have console log the value both the `routePoints` and the clicked point in the quest. you may take a look, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: obviously the problem here is the wrong frame placement leading to lng < 0 that causes `contain` calculation you need to review your reference frame parent element

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example in codesandbox.io or something similar? It would be easier to receive help this way.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this [example](https://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) in docs it is similar tou your use case,

> One common mistake when using `CRS.Simple` is assuming that the map units equal image pixels. In this case, the map covers 1000x1000 units, but the image is 2315x2315 pixels big. Different cases will call for one pixel = one map unit, or 64 pixels = one map unit, or anything. Think in map units in a grid, and then add your layers (`L.ImageOverlays`, `L.Markers` and so on) accordingly

you can find a section explaining "Pixels vs. map units" in Leaft.

**Note also:** coordinates in `CRS.Simple` take the form of `[y, x]` instead of `[x, y]`, in the same way Leaflet uses `[lat, lng]` instead of `[lng, lat]`.

Comment: hey, can u like give an example for to map between the `map unit` and `image pixel`? because right now my problem is, the image overlay, the bound is decide in runtime, therefore I dont know how to map it with the map unit.

Comment: @ken did you see the example?

Comment: I see it, but not sure how it work in react. is ok, later I will try again. thanks

Comment: @ken try to inverse values in your routePoints objects, set `lat` as `lng` and `lng` as `lat`